# Detected unclean shutdown - /data/db/mongod.lock is not empty

Tags: mongodb

Как исправить ошибку?

Mac os если работать 5 дней подряд не перезапускается. То есть висит закрыв все программы несколько минут. Дальше,  нажимаю кнопку принудительного отключения, но при перезагрузке слетает mongo находящийся в докере.

Пишет 
Detected unclean shutdown - /data/db/mongod.lock is not empty.

Если почистить папку /data/db то mongo снова запускается.
Но как восстановить данные?

```
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
2019-12-30T07:26:38.547+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=f348f9c6ccdd
2019-12-30T07:26:38.548+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.10
2019-12-30T07:26:38.548+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 078f28920cb24de0dd479b5ea6c66c644f6326e9
2019-12-30T07:26:38.548+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
2019-12-30T07:26:38.548+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2019-12-30T07:26:38.548+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-12-30T07:26:38.548+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-12-30T07:26:38.548+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: debian81
2019-12-30T07:26:38.548+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-12-30T07:26:38.548+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-12-30T07:26:38.548+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2019-12-30T07:26:38.560+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2019-12-30T07:26:38.564+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=487M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2019-12-30T07:26:39.231+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31802) [1577690799:231718][1:0x7f53809b6d40], file:_mdb_catalog.wt, WT_SESSION.open_cursor: /data/db/_mdb_catalog.wt: handle-read: pread: failed to read 4096 bytes at offset 131072: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error
2019-12-30T07:26:39.232+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Invariant failure: ret resulted in status UnknownError: -31802: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_session_cache.cpp 95
2019-12-30T07:26:39.232+0000 I -        [initandlisten]

***aborting after invariant() failure


2019-12-30T07:26:39.250+0000 F -        [initandlisten] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).

 0x55f20aa1a641 0x55f20aa19859 0x55f20aa19d3d 0x7f537f612890 0x7f537f28d067 0x7f537f28e448 0x55f209cc4667 0x55f20a7255b6 0x55f20a72338c 0x55f20a71f9c4 0x55f20a71e1ec 0x55f20a70b99b 0x55f20a652029 0x55f20a709667 0x55f20a5fc8b0 0x55f209cb08fe 0x55f209cd0276 0x7f537f279b45 0x55f209d2f4cf
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"55F2094A9000","o":"1571641","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"55F2094A9000","o":"1570859"},{"b":"55F2094A9000","o":"1570D3D"},{"b":"7F537F603000","o":"F890"},{"b":"7F537F258000","o":"35067","s":"gsignal"},{"b":"7F537F258000","o":"36448","s":"abort"},{"b":"55F2094A9000","o":"81B667","s":"_ZN5mongo25fassertFailedWithLocationEiPKcj"},{"b":"55F2094A9000","o":"127C5B6","s":"_ZN5mongo17WiredTigerSession9getCursorERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEmb"},{"b":"55F2094A9000","o":"127A38C","s":"_ZN5mongo16WiredTigerCursorC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEmbPNS_16OperationContextE"},{"b":"55F2094A9000","o":"12769C4","s":"_ZN5mongo21WiredTigerRecordStore6CursorC1EPNS_16OperationContextERKS0_b"},{"b":"55F2094A9000","o":"12751EC","s":"_ZN5mongo21WiredTigerRecordStoreC1EPNS_16OperationContextENS_10StringDataES3_NSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEbbllPNS_14CappedCallbackEPNS_20WiredTigerSizeStorerE"},{"b":"55F2094A9000","o":"126299B","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngine14getRecordStoreEPNS_16OperationContextENS_10StringDataES3_RKNS_17CollectionOptionsE"},{"b":"55F2094A9000","o":"11A9029","s":"_ZN5mongo15KVStorageEngineC1EPNS_8KVEngineERKNS_22KVStorageEngineOptionsE"},{"b":"55F2094A9000","o":"1260667"},{"b":"55F2094A9000","o":"11538B0","s":"_ZN5mongo20ServiceContextMongoD29initializeGlobalStorageEngineEv"},{"b":"55F2094A9000","o":"8078FE"},{"b":"55F2094A9000","o":"827276","s":"main"},{"b":"7F537F258000","o":"21B45","s":"__libc_start_main"},{"b":"55F2094A9000","o":"8864CF"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.4.10", "gitVersion" : "078f28920cb24de0dd479b5ea6c66c644f6326e9", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "4.9.184-linuxkit", "version" : "#1 SMP Tue Jul 2 22:58:16 UTC 2019", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "b" : "55F2094A9000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "004E9FAB8E542F8BABDB0274A211B1E9D15DEDF1" }, { "b" : "7FFE3D18D000", "path" : "linux-vdso.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "09E243C2FB482669406CABA88FAD799413F2A375" }, { "b" : "7F538053F000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "21115992A1F885E1ACE88AADA60F126AD9759D03" }, { "b" : "7F5380143000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "FD6376149047833953B0269E84DE181CA45DBE90" }, { "b" : "7F537FF3B000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A63C95FB33CCA970E141D2E13774B997C1CF0565" }, { "b" : "7F537FD37000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D70B531D672A34D71DB42EB32B68E63F2DCC5B6A" }, { "b" : "7F537FA36000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "152C93BA3E8590F7ED0BCDDF868600D55EC4DD6F" }, { "b" : "7F537F820000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D5FB04F64B3DAEA6D6B68B5E8B9D4D2BC1A6E1FC" }, { "b" : "7F537F603000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9DA9387A60FFC196AEDB9526275552AFEF499C44" }, { "b" : "7F537F258000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "48C48BC6ABB794461B8A558DD76B29876A0551F0" }, { "b" : "7F53807A0000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1D98D41FBB1EABA7EC05D0FD7624B85D6F51C03C" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x41) [0x55f20aa1a641]
 mongod(+0x1570859) [0x55f20aa19859]
 mongod(+0x1570D3D) [0x55f20aa19d3d]
 libpthread.so.0(+0xF890) [0x7f537f612890]
 libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37) [0x7f537f28d067]
 libc.so.6(abort+0x148) [0x7f537f28e448]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo25fassertFailedWithLocationEiPKcj+0x0) [0x55f209cc4667]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo17WiredTigerSession9getCursorERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEmb+0x106) [0x55f20a7255b6]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo16WiredTigerCursorC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEmbPNS_16OperationContextE+0x4C) [0x55f20a72338c]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo21WiredTigerRecordStore6CursorC1EPNS_16OperationContextERKS0_b+0x64) [0x55f20a71f9c4]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo21WiredTigerRecordStoreC1EPNS_16OperationContextENS_10StringDataES3_NSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEbbllPNS_14CappedCallbackEPNS_20WiredTigerSizeStorerE+0x47C) [0x55f20a71e1ec]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngine14getRecordStoreEPNS_16OperationContextENS_10StringDataES3_RKNS_17CollectionOptionsE+0x23B) [0x55f20a70b99b]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15KVStorageEngineC1EPNS_8KVEngineERKNS_22KVStorageEngineOptionsE+0x679) [0x55f20a652029]
 mongod(+0x1260667) [0x55f20a709667]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo20ServiceContextMongoD29initializeGlobalStorageEngineEv+0x6B0) [0x55f20a5fc8b0]
 mongod(+0x8078FE) [0x55f209cb08fe]
 mongod(main+0x966) [0x55f209cd0276]
 libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xF5) [0x7f537f279b45]
 mongod(+0x8864CF) [0x55f209d2f4cf]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
```

Comment: А удалить этот один-единственный файл пробовали?

Comment: удалил mongod.lock - ничего не поменялось